# Custom DNS Server

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, dns-hosting

Can I host a DNS server on a static WAN IP and use that as the DNS server assigned via DHCP on another network with separate WAN IP

I would imagine this would be fine considering I can use google's dns or OpenDNS' instead of the servers given by default from my ISP.

If this is possible, wondering if there are any security considerations to take or if I would just DMZ the DNS server itself

Comment: This is actually how all (public) DNS Servers work. On the security considerations, you'd want to ensure you're not exposing internal information and had secured the host appropriately for Internet-facing use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it but you must set your DNS as recursive server to allow clients to get resolved domain. Good practice is to allow recursive replies just for requests coming from some allowed IPs / networks. Also if DNS is exposed to public you just need to take care and have it always up to date.